# Finnish virkatodistus when living in Denmark

Tags: denmark, documentation, finnish-citizens

For matters of inheritance and Finnish bureaucracy I need a *virkatodistus/elää-todistus,* which proves that I am alive and thus can inherit.

I live in Denmark. The document provided by the Finnish *maistraatti* only covers the time when I lived in Finland. How can I get the relevant document?

I can think of three possible ways, one of which is expensive and slow.

- Ask the Finnish Ministry of foreign affairs to procure the documentation. This costs at least 100 €. [Reference](https://um.fi/asiakirjojen-ja-osoitetietojen-hankkiminen-ulkomailta).
- Maybe the Finnish embassy could prove that I am alive if I appear there with a passport? I cannot find information concerning this.
- Maybe the Danish authorities can create a relevant document. Since the Nordic countries are very good at accepting the documentation of each other, there is hope for this to be true.

Comment: _Ask_ the Finnish embassy?